# MCP251x driver missing

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, nvidia, canbus

I'm trying to install the `mcp251x` driver on a Linux system with kernel 4.9.253-tegra and I used the command:

```
  # modprobe mcp251x
```

I checked with the command

```
  # dmesg | grep mcp251x
```

but it doesn't show anything.

The driver exists in the folder,

`/lib/modules/4.9.253-tegra/kernel/drivers/net/can/spi/mcp251x.ko`

and even then it doesn't load.

How to install this driver correctly in this kernel version?

To edit:

1. I use jetson kernel 4.9.253-tegra
2. I insert mcp251x with modprobe. lsmod output show

   vcan                    3597  0

   can                    46600  0

   mcp251x                13742  0

   can_dev                13592  1 mcp251x

   fuse                  104554  3

   xt_conntrack            3609  1

   ipt_MASQUERADE          2346  1

   nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4     3111  1 ipt_MASQUERADE

   nf_conntrack_netlink    29413  0

   nfnetlink               7959  2 nf_conntrack_netlink

   xt_addrtype             3670  2

   iptable_filter          2481  1

   iptable_nat             2882  1

   nf_conntrack_ipv4      11992  2

   nf_defrag_ipv4          1836  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4

   nf_nat_ipv4             6712  1 iptable_nat

   nf_nat                 20406  2 nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4

   nf_conntrack          106659  6 nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat

   br_netfilter           16216  0

   zram                   25920  4

   overlay                48718  0

   userspace_alert         5828  0

   nvgpu                1589200  13

   ip_tables              19441  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat

   x_tables               28951  5 ip_tables,iptable_filter,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_addrtype,xt_conntrack
3. the command

   dmesg | grep -i mcp

dont show nothing.

Comment: Have you done a [modprobe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/modprobe.8.html)? and does modprobe see this module?

Comment: can you use lsmod to list modules? The module may be loaded but possibly, you don't have any device actually connected or described in your device tree.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni i connect a mcp2515 on j41, this works with arduino, I tested each pin with a led.  Isnt a hardware problem, is purelly sofware. I added more information on question. How to verify device tree ?

Comment: mcp251x is present in lsmod so it is already loaded. Probably you didn't add the node in your device tree.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni how to do that ?